# Put script src tags at top of body vs put script src tags at bottom of body

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I heard that I should place the script tags right before the closing body tag. However, when I do this, my angularJS expressions do not seem to compute correctly for some reason. When I place the script tags right before the closing body tag, "{{value}}" displays on the page which I do not want. However, when I move the script tags to right after the opening body tag, the page works correctly to display "2". Can anyone explain what happened?

**Put script right before closing body tags and page incorrectly displays "{{value}}"**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
      <meta chrset="UTF 8">
      <title>Event Registration</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">

  </head>

  <body>

      <div ng-app="sampleApp" ng-controller="AngularController">
          <h1> Guru99 Global Event</h1>
          {{value}}
      </div>
      <script>
          var sampleApp = angular.module('sampleApp', []);
          sampleApp.controller('AngularController', function($scope) {
              $scope.a = 1;
              $scope.b = 1;
              $scope.value = $scope.$eval('a+b');
          })
      </script>

      <script src="lib/angular.js"></script>
      <script src="lib/bootstrap.js"></script>
      <script src="lib/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
      <script src="lib/app.js"></script>

  </body>

  </html>
```

**Put script right after opening body tags and page correctly displays "2"**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
      <meta chrset="UTF 8">
      <title>Event Registration</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">

  </head>

  <body>
      <script src="lib/angular.js"></script>
      <script src="lib/bootstrap.js"></script>
      <script src="lib/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
      <script src="lib/app.js"></script>

      <div ng-app="sampleApp" ng-controller="AngularController">
          <h1> Guru99 Global Event</h1>
          {{value}}
      </div>
      <script>
          var sampleApp = angular.module('sampleApp', []);
          sampleApp.controller('AngularController', function($scope) {
              $scope.a = 1;
              $scope.b = 1;
              $scope.value = $scope.$eval('a+b');
          })
      </script>

  </body>

  </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your script tag in the header.

That recommendation of putting it just before the closing tag, is so that the browser downloads the content of the page first, then the user can see something while the javascript is being downloaded. If the script tag is at the top, then the user will stare at a white page for a little bit longer, until the javascript finishes downloading, then the content will start rendering.

In your case, it seems you don't want the user to see any content before the javascript runs (the {{value}} raw html), so it makes total sense to ignore that recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple. All of the angular functions,handlers,components & directives are initialized in `angulatjs` script. When you load the `angularjs` at the bottom. The browser will load the script after load the `HTML`. So at the beginning there is no `angular` so It will not capture `{{value}}` so it just a plain text for browser, Browser will show `{{value}}` directly.

When you load at the top. The angular will be loaded. So angular knows how to handle `{{value}}`. So it will bind the value for `{{value}}`.

Answer (score 0):

The browser "reads" your html from top to bottom and when it encounters javascript or css it will stop rendering until it processes it entirely.  This is why in many cases it is suggested that scripts be placed at the bottom.  Usually the script is unable to do its "job" until the entire page renders, anyway, so why block the initial render?

That being said, this is only tangentially the reason for the behavior you are seeing.  The general answer for your question is that javascript, as well, is "read" top to bottom, so any variable not declared before it is used is undefined (there is a concept called "hoisting" which affects this as well, but of no relevance at the moment).  In your case, specifically, the `angular` object is not yet declared (had you opened your console tools you would have seen that as an error) and therefore you cannot call any of the methods associated with that object.  `angular` is declared in angular.js, which is included *after* your script in the first example, and (correctly) *before* in the second.

If you simply move *your* script to the bottom of the included scripts in the first example you will see that your application should run as expected